# Is this the right way to setup socket server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, web-development-server, use-ref

I have hosted the socket server at Heroku.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8900;

const io = require("socket.io")(port, {
  cors: {
    origin:"https://connectbook.netlify.com/",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // when user connect
  console.log("A user connected");
}
```

Frontend code:

```
const socket = useRef(io('ws://connectbook-chat-api.herokuapp.com/'));

useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io('ws://connectbook-chat-api.herokuapp.com/');
    socket.current.on('getMessage', (data) => {
      setArrivalMessage({
        sender: data.senderId,
        text: data.text,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

The execution is not reaching console.log('A user connected') on running both the files

Comment: The server code looks good to me, however did you try `https://connectbook-chat-api.herokuapp.com/` in the `client` code?

Comment: That is also not working.